# SoX clipping audio even when -G flag is used

Tags: audio, sox

I'm doing batch conversion of bit depth and sample rate with SoX using the following command:

```
sox -G $infile -b 16 $outfile rate 44100 dither
```

I'm using the -G flag to prevent clipping in the converted files, but for some files I still get the warning:

> sox.exe WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?

Why might this still be happening?

Comment: I'm curious, what happens when you remove `dither` from the command line, does it still report clipping? I'm asking because the [manual](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) claims it automatically adds dither as demanded by the reduction of bit depth. Another thing worth trying is `dither -s`.

Comment: You're correct, I get the same results when I remove the dither command. Regarding the -s flag, noise shaping should not be used in this particular application, as the audio files will undergo further processing down the line.

Comment: I can add that backing off the volume to 0.95 seems to have fixed the issue, but the original question stands.

Comment: Just one more thing I forgot to ask earlier: when removing `-G`, is the number of samples being clipped still the same, or does the number go up? The latter would suggest SoX has an inaccuracy (e.g. a rounding error) when estimating the amount of headroom needed in the output stage.

Comment: The latter: many more samples are clipped.